# HTML5 data-target loading page?

Tags: jquery, css, html, loading

I have some HTML5 here:

```
<li class="tile bing" data-target-activation="submit" data-target="loading">
  <div>
    <form action="http://bing.com/" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="q" />
    </form>
    <h2>Bing</h2>
  </div>
</li>
```

When the user clicks on the search icon it takes them to a "loading" page via the 
`data-target="loading"` attribute. It basically slides to this page.

How can I simply create a hyperlink which will slide to the loading page then redirect to a blog on my website?

**EDIT: is it possible to create some sort of response.redirect within the form block?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
    $('li#blogLink.tile').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($("#page_blog.page.current").length) { // section exists
        $("h1").text("Loading...");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "http://www.site.co.uk/blog/";
        }, 2000);
    }   
});
```